# Unable to hide / change visibility of a react native component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I have a spinner progress bar which shows spinning wheel when user is losing in and once done, it hides. I am using a state for the same when view is loaded spinner is hidden due to visibility state set to false and when login button is clicked its set to true, until this it works but after the result, I want to hide it which doesn't work. Here is the code

```
export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Login',
    headerTintColor:'black'
};
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { loginText: 'username',pwdText:'password',loading:false };

    this.onLogin = this.onLogin.bind(this);

}
onLogin() {
    this.setState({
        loading: true
    });



    var params = 'username=';
    params = params.concat(this.state.loginText,'&password=');
    params = params.concat(this.state.pwdText);


    console.log(params);

    fetch("http://example.com/app/loginUser.php", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
        }),
        body: params // <-- Post parameters
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {

            console.log(responseJson.result);
            if(responseJson.result != "false") {

                this.setState({
                    loading: false
                });

                Alert.alert(
                    'Info',
                    'Login successful.',
                    [
                        {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'}
                    ],
                    { cancelable: false }
                )
            }
            else {
                Alert.alert(
                    'Info',
                    'Unable to login.',
                    [
                        {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'}
                    ],
                    { cancelable: false }
                )
                this.setState({
                    loading: false
                });

            }
        })
        .catch((error) =>{
            console.error(error);
        });


}
render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
        <ImageBackground
            source={require('./images/marble.jpg')}
            style={styles.backgroundImage}>

            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Spinner visible={this.state.loading} textContent={"Loading..."} textStyle={{color: '#FFF'}} />

                <Image style = {styles.logoFit} resizeMode="contain"  source={require('./images/Logo1.png')}/>

                <View>
                    <TextInput clearTextOnFocus={true} style={styles.textInput} value={this.state.loginText }
                               onChangeText={(textInputValue1) => this.setState({loginText:textInputValue1})}></TextInput>

                    <TextInput clearTextOnFocus={true} style={styles.textInput} value={this.state.pwdText}
                               onChangeText={(textInputValue2) => this.setState({pwdText:textInputValue2})}></TextInput>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.buttonSection}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.onLogin}>
                        <View style = { styles.donebutton}>ß
                            <Text style = {{color: 'white'}}>Login</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>

        </ImageBackground>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: can you do a console.log(this) after this line console.log(responseJson.result); and tell me what was the output?

Comment: Two things could be an issue, make sure your spinner component is working properly. That is check using a timeout if the spinner is shown and hidden properly without fetch. Second check if your fetch is resolved properly without any errors, to make sure add your setState also to the catch block.

Comment: @RaviRaj component works fine its the state that doesnt change inside then, it never goes to catch block thus fetch gets resolved just fine .

Comment: @vishaldharankar is your Spinner made using the Modal component?. Comment out both the `Alert` section and check if the Spinner is getting hidden.

Comment: @RaviRaj yes it uses modal

Answer (score 1):

Check the state is getting set or not
this.setState({ loading: false},() => {console.log(this.state.loading)});

if its not getting set try forceUpdate
this.setState({ loading: false},() => {this.forceUpdate()});

Comment: ok that helps, its updating but still the spinner isn't removed / visibility isn't set to false and updated

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @RaviRaj in one of the comment and suggested by @Pramod in above answer, I checked for the state and found that state was getting set.
And then as Spinner is modal and Alert is modal too ( thats what I guess) it was messing up. After removing Alert it started working as expected. 
There is an issue reported here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11084